# is there any solution to download a file from aws s3 bucket with aws lambda but file size should be 1gb or more?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, clamav

I want to scan file by uising ClamAV from s3 bucket with AWS lambda but size of the local storage in aws lambda that is /tmp 512MB . Im my case i want to download file from s3 bucket in AWS lambda but file size must be grater then 1 GB. Please help me out if anyone knows.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

You could also setup [EFS for lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-efs.html) to have virtual unlimited space which can also be shared with other services, such as EC2, ECS and other Lambda functions.

Comment: If i'll use EFS,  so i can download large file directly to EFS like/efs instead /tmp ?

Comment: @AminAli Yes, that's exactly what you can do.

Comment: @Marcin AFAIK the container 10 GB is only for the image size. The local storage is still limited to 512 MB

Comment: @Korgen Thanks for clarification. I removed it from the answer.

Comment: Just be aware that EFS performance with a single service accessing it is fairly horrible. It will be a few orders of magnitude slower than accessing a local file system like `/tmp`. If that causes problems (like causing your Lambda function to run longer than 15 minutes) then you'll need to look for other ways to run your application, like ECS+Fargate as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda Limit is 512 Mb [Lambda Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html), and cannot be changed.

> The following quotas apply to function configuration, deployments, and execution. They cannot be changed.
>
> /tmp directory storage 512 MB

If you need to run task that needs more space, one option would be convert the lambda to a container and run it as a fargate task.

The limits for fargate are 200Gb [Fargate Tasks storage information](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html)

> By default, Amazon ECS tasks hosted on Fargate using platform version 1.4.0 or later receive a minimum of 20 GiB of ephemeral storage. The total amount of ephemeral storage can be increased, up to a maximum of 200 GiB, by specifying the ephemeralStorage parameter in your task definition.

Comment: can i use EFS for downloading large file instead of /tmp directory in aws lambda?